# Yum RPM database corrupted on Red Hat OpenShift

Tags: linux, display

`Yum` is not working on Red Hat `OpenShift`, meaning I can't install anything to demonise my `node.js` app, and I don't have permission to rectify it.  Can I install screen from source?

Error:

```
error: cannot open Packages database in /var/lib/rpm
CRITICAL:yum.main:

Error: rpmdb open failed
```